# Scala OnCreate alternative implementation

Tags: scala, logging

I was waiting for 2.12 to be able to use the [onCreate](https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-4330) hook, but it seems that it's been pushed off until 2.13. Are there any suggestions for a way to make a decent alternative? In essence, I have a trait and an abstract class as follows:

```
trait Issue {
    def details: ...
    def logic: ...
    def toSimpleView: ...
}

abstract class AbstractIssue extends(source: IssueSource) extends Issue{
    val extraDetail: ...
}
```

There exist multiple different implementations of the `AbstractIssue`, and on the initialization of an issue I want to grab it and put a simplified representation of it into a database, then return it to the code as usual. The goal is to only put it into the database after all the fields in the child class have been initialized, and also to only have to write this code in the `AbstractIssue` and `Issue` to avoid hunting down every existing child `Issue`.

My gut reaction to this problem is to add this to the abstract constructor:

```
abstract class AbstractIssue extends(source: IssueSource) extends Issue{
    val extraDetail: ...
    Future { Thread.sleep(2000) }.foreach(_ => InsertIssue(this.toSimpleView)) }
}
```

Unfortunately, that's a terrible way to do it, and I'm struggling to come up with a clean solution. Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Perhaps DelayedInit, which lets you do what you like with initializer. Maybe you need a trick to know when your object is ready enough.

Comment: Unfortunately DelayedInit is deprecated AFAIK. But yes, if I can find a way to signal when all the required fields are ready I could just make a Future that waits until then

Comment: You could make `toSimpleView` return a `Future`-like type like `def toSimpleView: Task[???]` or `def toSimpleView: Future[???]`. The method (or something else in your concrete class) can then complete the promise when it has been completely initialized. It seems like a *very bad* design, though! Please consider moving the `InsertIssue` outsside of the `AbstractIssue` and let the one who is responsible of creating Issues decide if he wants to put them into DB.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I ended up doing as a hack until onCreate comes out:

```
def hackToHandleAfterInitialization(handler:IssueHandler):Future[Unit] = {
import scala.concurrent.blocking
Future {
  var continue = true
  while (continue) {
    try {
      blocking(synchronized(handler.handleProblem(this)))
      continue = false
    } catch {
      case un:UninitializedFieldError =>
        Thread.sleep(5)
        continue = true
    }
  }
  Unit
}
```

And then in the abstract class:

```
abstract class AbstractIssue extends(source: IssueSource) extends Issue{
    val extraDetail: ...
    hackTohandleAfterInitialization(DefaultHandler())
}
```